# Why i get puppeteer ENOENT at npm install in my project?

Tags: angular, puppeteer, node-modules, npm-install

Long story short: i just want to execute npm install on a project.
I get this message:

```
2529 timing build:link Completed in 133ms
2530 info run puppeteer@9.1.1 install node_modules/puppeteer node install.js
2531 info run puppeteer@9.1.1 install { code: 'ENOENT', signal: undefined }
2532 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 18454ms
2533 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
2534 timing command:install Completed in 96274ms
2535 verbose stack Error: spawn bash ENOENT
2535 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
2535 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
2535 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
2536 verbose pkgid puppeteer@9.1.1
2537 verbose cwd C:\d\work\bns\backend
2538 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22000
2539 verbose node v16.17.0
2540 verbose npm  v8.19.1
2541 error code ENOENT
2542 error syscall spawn bash
2543 error path C:\d\work\bns\backend\node_modules\puppeteer
2544 error errno -4058
2545 error enoent spawn bash ENOENT
2546 error enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
2546 error enoent
2547 verbose exit -4058
2548 timing npm Completed in 96388ms
2549 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1663706237073
2550 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:build 1663706314689
2551 verbose unfinished npm timer build 1663706314695
2552 verbose unfinished npm timer build:deps 1663706314695
2553 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install 1663706314883
2554 verbose unfinished npm timer build:run:install:node_modules/puppeteer 1663706314884
2555 verbose code -4058
2556 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I've tried to clone the project again but with the same result.
Also tried to uninstall and reinstall node, npm.
This project works just fine on other devices.
What should i do/try?

Comment: Have you tried removing `node_modules` directory from `C:\d\work\bns\backend\node_modules`, clean the cache with `npm cache clean –force` and then reinstall all with `npm install`?

Comment: @Baumi i have tried that